# How do I change the URL of a Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to change the URL of my Wordpress pages but I am unable to create a custom URL.

For instance www.mydomain.com/**link/** I would like to change to www.mydomain.com/**one/two/three/link/** however when I edit the permalink it deletes the forward slashes and looks like this: www.mydomain.com/**onetwothreelink/**

I have recently had my site converted to Wordpress and need to bring the URL structure back to how it was both for Google and SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this through Wordpress you would have to create a page called "one" a page called "two" and a page called "three". From their you would have to make page "one" the parent of "two" and page "two" the parent of "three" and so on and so forth. You can do this by going to the page you'd like to edit on the wordpress backend, then selecting the parent in the "Page Attributes" meta box right below publish.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I had thought of this previously but figured there would be a much cleaner way... To be more specific; I want www.mydomain.com/ **duplication/disc/cd/** and www.mydomain.com/ **duplication/disc/dvd/** and www.mydomain.com/ **duplication/media/usb/** with the menu showing only: **CD | DVD | USB** -- To reiterate I have no duplication page, disc page or media page at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using category Permalinks. Go to **Settings -> Permalinks** and set the custom structure to: `/%category%/%postname%/`.

Make sure when selecting the category for the page that you only select the subcategory. If you select the subcategory and parent category/categories the subcategories won't show in the URL.